# Getter & Setter generator does not show up Netbean 8.0.2

Tags: netbeans-8

Netbeans for PHP v8.0.2 said to generate getter and setter methods just press Crtl + I (Mac OS) and select 'Getter & setter' option but it does not show up as an option in there. Anyone know how to activate this please?

Comment: Try with this: Alt+Insert: fn + alt/option + return

Answer (score 1):

> Just right click in side the class body,not over the class variables
>   and choose insert code option as shown in third image.
>   link:http://w.planetnetbeans.org/topic28565.html

[image: getters and setters]

[image: generate option]
[image: insert code option]